# Minimum of dates selection in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a date clause for the selection of my data. There are two date fields on my form 'oberflache' which are `start` and `end`. I want to choose the minimum of two fields. i.e it should only choose the record based on the date which comes first.Here is the code am trying with.

```
    PARAMETERS [Forms]![oberflache]![start] DateTime, [Forms]![oberflache]![end]  DateTime;
SELECT Lau.AN, Lau.Ve, Lau.Du, Lau.Sta, Lau.A, Lau.B, Lau.SW, Lau.Po
FROM Laufzettel 
    WHERE 
        Min(Fix(Lau.A)) Between Forms![oberflache]!start And Forms![oberflache]!end)) 
        Or 
        Min(Fix(Lau.B)) Between Forms![oberflache]!start And Forms![oberflache]!end;
```

Where AN,Ve,Du,Sta,A,B,SW,Po are the fields from the table Lau. So the cases are

```
Lau.A              Lau.B
1.11.2016          5.11.2016
2.11.2016          3.11.2016
20.10.2016         4.11.2016
4.11.2016          28.10.2016
```

Here when I give the start and end Dates as `1.11.2016` and 
`4.11.2016`. I want the records to be selected in such a way that if the date of Lau.A or Lau.B is before `1.11.2016` just like in the 3rd record or 4th record they must be left out and the first two are selected.

With the code I tried

It gives me an error that `cannot have aggregate function in WHERE clause`. What is an alternative for the above?

Comment: It is not clear what is your aim. Do you want to use Lau.A or Lau.B whichewer is smaler?

Comment: Perhaps... `WHERE IIF(Fix(Lau.A)<fix(lau.B), Lau.A,Lau.B) Between Forms![oberflache]!start And Forms![oberflache]!end)`

Comment: The error is very clear, if you want use `MIN` you need use it on `HAVING`. Now how you want us to give you and alternative if you dont explain what your query is supose to do. What are `Lau.A` and `Lau.B`? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  SQL does not allow you to use `MIN()` in the `WHERE` clause, so your snippet of code makes no sense.